# Matlab with database and edit box

Tags: database, matlab, matlab-guide

i programing license plate recognition programs, and appeared problem. So after few examples i figure out my code

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
conn = database('baze', 'root', 'root', 'Vendor', 'MYSQL', 'Server', 'localhost', 'PortNumber', 3306);
a = get(handles.edit8,'String');
if iscell(a) && numel(a) == 1
    a = a{1};
end
if ~ischar(a) || isempty(a);
    error('A valid string must be supplied!');
end
sqlquery = ['select vardas, pavarde, laipsnis, pareigos, telefonas, marke, numeris, tarnyba from info '...
       'where numeris = ' '''' a ''''];
curs = exec(conn, sqlquery);
curs = fetch(curs);
curs.data
close(curs)
close(conn)
```

All this i got in Matlab command window, but if i have gui aplication and i want retrive value in gui wich have edit text box. Example: after i input car plate number got 'vardas' in edit1 and 'pavarde' in edit2.

Comment: So, you get always `0` when doing `a = get(handles.edit8,'String');` ?

Comment: yes, and i dont know were i made mistake.

Comment: Either `handles.edit8` is not hat you think it is, or `String` is not the property name

Comment: edit8 is right i am make sure, but about string i.m not bacause in edit8 i write similalry - ASD123 etc. Maybe problem is in sqlquery where sentence is 'a'. and cant connect with handles.edit8

Comment: If you display (or debug) the variable 'a' just before creating the sqlquery string, is it still 0? Looks more like you have to remove the quotes around the 'a' when creating the sqlquery command to really evaluate the plate string.

Comment: i little change code and works perfectly now, but i have new question for you. All this i got in Matlab command window, but if i have gui aplication and i want retrive value in gui wich have edit text box. Example: i after i input car plate number got 'vardas' in edit1 and 'pavarde' in edit2.

Comment: someone can help?